# What DLL's does DirectX 5 use?

Tags: windows-8, compatibility, directx, hook

I know directX 9 uses many DLL's, but the main DLL is `d3d9.dll` which I can replace with my own one and so "hook" into an application using DirectX 9. I can do the same for directx 8. But I have a game which crashes and it uses directx 5, but placing my custom `d3d5.dll` in the games directory does not load my DLL file. (DirectX to openGL wrapper). What is the main DLL used by DirectX 5 for creating a device (a.k.a. what is the equivalent of `d3d9.dll->CreateDevice(Ex)` ?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems, all directx versions from one up to 7 use "ddraw.dll" as their main DLL and version 8 uses d3d8.dll, version 9 d3d9.dll. As for version 10 and 11 d3d10.dll and d3d11.dll respectively.

Comment: See also [Wine Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/DDraw). Very much for the records, [ddrawex](https://sourceforge.net/p/dxwnd/discussion/general/thread/e9640a75/) also exists but nothing uses it.